# Uploading multiple files with data via Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<form action="ajax.php" method="POST" id="request-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<select name="car">
   <option value="">Choose</option>
 </select>

 <input type="text" name="address"/>
 <input type="text" name="zip"/>

 <input type="file" name="typeoneimage" class="typeone"/>
 <input type="file" name="typetwoimage" class="typetwo"/>

</form>

<input type="button" value="Add more file"/>
```

Thats my basic form, but by click on button more input tags of file type can be added via jquery, like

```
<input type="file" name="typeoneimage" class="typeone"/>
<input type="file" name="typetwoimage" class="typetwo"/>
```

Here is my javascript code to upload that form's data, but the only the last files are sent to the server via ajax, the rest of the files are missing, I want to send these files as an array typeone images in one array and typetwo images in send array. How can I achieve this, please guide me.

```
function postRequest(car,address,zip,typeoneimg,typetwoimg)
        {
            return $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"ajax.php",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                async:false,
                cache:false,
                data:{"car":car,"address":address,"zip":zip,"typeOneImage":typeoneimg,"typeTwoImage":typetwoimage}
            });
}

var typeOneImages=new Array();
var typeTwoImages=new Array();

$(form).on("submit",function(e){

        $.each(".typeone",function(){
            typeOneImages.push($(this).file[0]);
        });

        $.each(".typetwo",function(){
            typeTwoImages.push($(this).file[0]);
        });

        //postRequest function call here


e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: kindly read my question carefully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168040/upload-multiple-files-with-php-and-jquery/24168617#24168617