# How to get the form file field in jquery to upload image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have below html

```
This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>
        <div class="imguploadpath" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#CCC;">
          <form name="myFormName" id ="myFormId" action="" method="post">
             <input type="file" name="img" id = "image_pe">
             <br/><br/><br/><br/>
             <input id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="">
          </form>
        </div>
```

I am trying to get the file field values to upload the file in php using below script

```
jQuery( "#cmdSubmit" ).on( "click", function() {
   var file = jQuery('#image_pe').val();
```

//i have to send file property to php file in jquery ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php?files',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                {
                    // Success so call function to process the form
                    submitForm(event, data);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                // STOP LOADING SPINNER
            }
        });
       return false;

    });
```

but `var file` only return some temp path `c://fakepath/image.jpg`

how do upload in jquery and php, I need to pass the form field in php file, I know `value()` jquery function is wrong.

what is the correct way to do it ?

for php file upload i was thinking of using this script http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: Maybe this will help

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168040/upload-multiple-files-with-php-and-jquery/24168617#24168617][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168040/upload-multiple-files-with-php-and-jquery/24168617#24168617

Hope it helps

Comment: http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax .... this also helped me a lot to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
JQuery:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
            jQuery.each($('#image_pe')[0].files, function(i, file) {
             formdata.append('image_pe', file);
            });


            $.ajax({
                url: "/my.php",
                data : formdata,
                dataType : "json",
                type : "post",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data){

                },
                failure: function(){
                    $(this).addClass("error");
                }
            });
            return false;
```

PHP Code:

```
$file = $_FILES['image_pe'];
```

Comment: hi this solves the jquery problem but can u add php code as well ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this. This is might be very helpful for you

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload