# Can't upload multiple files using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

First of all this might be a silly question as there are many topics available on this but seriously I am not being able to get it straight and understand how to make it work.

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**

I am trying to upload multiple files using AJAX and PHP.

**PROBLEM**

- I cant figure out how to pass the data to the PHP script using AJAX.
  I don't want to use a form and a submit button for uploading.
- Tried using a form and submitting it using jQuery still couldn't make
  it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="heading">Upload your files seamlessly</div>
    <a href="#"><div id="upload" class="button" title="Upload your files"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div></a>
    <a href="view.php"><div id="view" class="button" title="View all files on my cloud"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div></a>
</div>

<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" multiple name="uploadfile[]" id="uploadfile" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload').click(function(){
        $('input[type=file]').click();
        return false;
    });

    $("#uploadfile").change(function(){
         //submit the form here  
         $('#fileupload').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile'])){

    $errors= array();

    foreach($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$key]; 
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       

        //$query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";

        $desired_dir="storage";

        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }
            else{                                   // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         //mysql_query($query);         
        }
        else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know: Using a form input, and post it, is the only way to upload local files from a browser.

Comment: You mean using a form?

Comment: The user of the browser has to give your html/javascript code access to local files. This is done with an `<input type="file">`. That's probably part of a form. But the user has to initiate the upload. Once that is done your javascript can take over. Submit button is not needed. In JQuery you can use `$(<form>).submit();`.

Comment: Is there no way without a form?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's wrong with using a form? You want to download files from an user's computer without their consent? The only files you can get at, without a form, are cookies.

Comment: I am not downloading files but allowing users to upload files without the need to press submit button. Actually I had seen something like this on script in github

Comment: You do not need a submit button. Even if you use a form.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: It's in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/submit

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/1022914) should help you with the JS part. You'll probably need to iterate over the files and append them to the FormData.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I updated my code but still no uploads take place. Check my updated code.

Comment: Your `<form>` tag is incomplete, you need an `action` attribute that refers to the php script that accepts the file upload. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: Even with an action attribute it doesn't work .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168040/upload-multiple-files-with-php-and-jquery/24168617#24168617

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of what you want to do.

**HTML**

Wrap your inputs within a form. Why? Because it is the easiest way to do it.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" multiple name="uploadfile[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

Attach an `onsubmit` event handler to your form. Use $.ajax() to send a POST request.

Pass your form element i.e. `this` into the constructor of a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and use it as your `data` when you send the request as shown below. You need to make sure that you set `processData` and `contentType` as `false` also for this to work.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // send request
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action, 
            type: this.method, 
            data: new FormData(this), // important
            processData: false, // important 
            contentType: false, // important
            success: function (res) {
                alert(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP (process.php)**

Let's clean up your PHP.

```
<?php
// always a good idea to turn on errors during development
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$dir = './storage';
$errors = [];

if (isset($_FILES['uploadfile'])) {
    $files = $_FILES['uploadfile'];
    // create directory if it does not exist
    !is_dir($dir) && mkdir($dir, 0700);
    // validate & upload files
    foreach (array_keys($files['tmp_name']) as $key) {
        $file = [
            'name' => $files['name'][$key],
            'size' => $files['size'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
            'type' => $files['type'][$key],
            'error' => $files['error'][$key]
        ];
        // skip if no file was given
        if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
            continue;
        }
        // get file extension
        $file['ext'] = strtolower(pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // generate a unique name (!)
        $file['name'] = uniqid() . '.' . $file['ext'];
        // validate
        if (!file_exists($file['tmp_name']) || 
            !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) ||
            $file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $errors[$key] = 'An unexpected error has occurred.';
        } elseif ($file['size'] > 2097152) {
            $errors[$key] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        // upload file
        } elseif (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir . '/' . $file['name'])) {
            $errors[$key] = 'File could not be uploaded.';
        }
    }
}

if ($errors) {
    print_r($errors);
} else {
    echo 'no errors';
}
?>
```

(!) Do keep in mind that [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is actually not unique.

Comment: I tried this but in any case it keeps alerting me with "No errors"

Comment: Debug the code by putting `echo`s at different points in the code and see where it fails from that. I ran this code on my local server and it worked fine.